# there is an issue on flutter app when run flutter run

Tags: flutter

ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl.cc(70)] Failed to setup Skia Gr context.
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:50930/6r2skviwLRI=/

```
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

is this firewall or antivirus software issue?

Comment: Are you using an emulator ?

Comment: yes.Genymotion .

Comment: Run your app from terminal with : `flutter run --enable-software-rendering`

Comment: It is working right now.what was the isue?

Comment: I think your emulator doesn't support hardware rendering or a problem with your computer graphic card, so you can change  your AVD  configuration  to `software rendering` .

Comment: On Android Studio :  `tools` > `AVD Manager` and edit your emulator's configuration .

Comment: I am grateful for your help.@HANSANI could you upvoted this one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess this might be your work around. It happens usually on emulators. So, let me know if that works out for you.

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering
```

`--enable-software-rendering` is the key, however, I can't find the issue tracker anywhere.

Comment: @ShalithaJayamal this is something the flutter is coming up with GPUs of Android Emulators. **You don't usually find that problem in iOS emulator though**.  On Real devices, the rendering happens fine. If that works for you, you can mark it as correct, and upvote it, if you want :)

Comment: great.I am new commer to flutter .upvoted.Happy learning

Comment: Thanks @ShalithaJayamal and `Welcome to Flutter Community`. This is a wonderful IDE to build the best Native Mobile Application. You will fall in love with that. Keep yourself updated with [Flutter Official Docs](https://flutter.dev/) and follow this channel for sure => [Flutter Official Youtube channel for Awesome Widgets and Classes](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwXdFgeE9KYzlDdR7TG9cMw). Godspeed!

Comment: Software rendering doesn't play nice with Google Maps currently.  :/ 
 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24738

Answer (score 6):

If you wanna run your app from terminal then simply enter the command

- `flutter run --enable-software-rendering`

If you are willing to run your app resolving this issue in android studio then

- `Run`->`Edit Configuration`-> in `Additional Arguments` field add this `--enable-software-rendering`  ->press `Apply` -> press `Ok`. Now restart your emulator again. Hope your problem will go.

Solution for VsCode :

- open `launch.json` file by going `Run` -> `Open Configuration` and
- add a specific argument  `"args": ["--enable-software-rendering", "-d", "all"]` like
- `"configurations": [

  ```
  {
      "name": "virtual_prescriber",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
      "args": ["--enable-software-rendering", "-d", "all"]
  }
  ```

  ]`
- finally go to `Run` -> `Run Without Debugging` .hope everything will work fine

Answer (score 0):

When your IDE is Android Studio,
At AVD Manager,
Click the pencil icon and  button,
then at [Emulated Performance]-[Graphics]
Select Software-GLES1.1
then [finish] button....
And it will be Ok ..